# How to find the dimension of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

If

$$A:=\left\{\ \begin {pmatrix} y_2 -y_3\\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{C^3} \  \right\}\subseteq\mathbb{C^3}$$
how do I find the dimension of $A$. I know that $A$ is linearly independent and is a subspace of $\mathbb{C^3}$ but how can I use this to find the dimension of $A$?

Comment: An infinite subset can't be linearly independent in a finite-dimensional space. To find the dimension, find a basis by specifying different values for the parameters.

Comment: There are two free variables, therefore ...?

Answer (score 1):

You can see as the elements of $A$, if $$y=(y_2-y_3,y_2,y_3) \in A$$ then

$$y=(y_2-y_3,y_2,y_3)=y_2(1,1,0)+y_3(-1,0,1).$$

You can check that  $$\{(1,1,0),(-1,0,1)\}$$ is a base for $A,$ thus $A$ is 2-dimensional.

Comment: Just a small edit. The second term should be $y_3(-1, 0, 1).$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$A$ is the range of the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: How'd you do it without using Matrices, since we haven't started on that yet?

Comment: @Ski Mask: Then, I would also go Olecram's way.